# How to instantiate a custom UIView subclass with init(frame:) with auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am making an ios App and is relying on AutoLayout constraints to set the sizes of views and subviews layout.

I made a custom subclass of an `UIScrollView`, see below. When I write its `init` method, I see its super class only has `init(frame:)` to override. But because I am using autolayout, I am not supposed to set the frame.

So how should I write the `init` method in my case? Shall I pass in a dummy `frame` value:

```
MyCollectionView: UIScrollView {

   init() {
        super.init(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0))
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
ViewController:UIViewController {

let myScrollView = MyScrollView()

}
```

Comment: Do you use xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about setting/not a frame as when you use autolauout

```
let myScrollView = MyScrollView()
myScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

the frame will has no effect with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` being set to `false` , so do

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
         setUp()
    }

    func setUp() {

    }

}
```

---

```
let gg = MyScrollView(frame: .zero)
gg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
// add constraints
```